# Should it be WAS or DID here?

Tags: verbs

The lyrics to *Black* by Pearl Jam go like:

> Sheets of empty canvas, untouched sheets of clay

> Were laid spread out before me, as her body once **did**...

I thought **was** was more appropriate than **did** above because it seems to make more sense to say *untouched sheets of clay were laid spread out before me as her body once [**was spread**]*, with the bracketed part left out because of ellipsis. But I've read **did** used instead of **was/were** countless times, and it's discomfited me every single time.

What is the rule here?

Comment: One or two other examples would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> untouched sheets of clay were laid spread out before me as her body
> once [was spread]

I interpreted this differently, i.e. *untouched sheets of clay were laid spread out before me as her body once [lay].*

Thus there is a case for both forms. We sometimes have to make allowances with song lyrics.

Comment: Ah, I see. Fair point that, @chasly. So the writer has used _did_ because he means to say _untouched.... were **laid** spread out... as her body once **did** [ lay spread out]_, right?

Comment: Yes, "as her body once did [lay]"

Comment: Thanks a lot, @chasly- supports Monica.

Comment: Don't look to song lyrics for good English.  They are usually written to sound good and fit the music, not necessarily to be grammatically correct.

Comment: @stangdon_ That's true but incidentally I was listening to this song a while back and the question had been with me for long. My bad, I couldn't come up with an example sentence from some good literary source. BTW, what is your take on this?

Comment: @User40475 I agree with you that "as her body was" is what I would normally say.  Using _did_ is a little bit like the [emphatic do](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-emphatic-do-1690590) but I could also read it "as her body did (spread out)".

Comment: @stangdon Thanks. I was watching a movie a while back and one character said something that is pertinent to this question. He said: "I used to be a lion. We all **did.**" And again I thought it should be "We all **were.**" Right?

Comment: @chasly- supports Monica your thoughts also?

Comment: @User40475 - You can get into deep water with this question. There are plenty of online arguments about the past tense of "used to" when employing the auxiliary verb "do".  Some say it should be "I did use to be X", some say "I did used to be X" and some say you can't say it at all.  My preference is to say, for example, "I did use to be a lion."  Therefore, according to me,  your sentence would become, "I used to be a lion. We all did use to be lions."  NOTE to everyone: I shall not get involved in any arguments about this. I've seen them all before. That's my answer. Take it or leave it.

Comment: Take it easy, man! It's just a question. I have already upvoted your answer and do follow your logic, @chasly :)

Comment: @User40475 - I'm not complaining about you or your question. My warning is for any native speakers who have strong opinions on this (and many do), that I'm not going to argue the point with them!  My answer to you is that "did" refers to "did use to" and so I find it perfectly acceptable.